# RoR: cannot get started with ezcrypto / ActiveCrypto

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, encryption

I want to encrypt a field stored in an ActiveRecord table.  A few helpful people pointed me towards [ezcrypto](http://ezcrypto.rubyforge.org/) which appears to be what I want.  Especially interesting is ActiveCrypto, as described in [ezcrypto.rubyforge.org/files/README_ACTIVE_CRYPTO.html](http://ezcrypto.rubyforge.org/files/README_ACTIVE_CRYPTO.html)

But I can't get it working.  I've added

```
gem 'ezcrypto', '0.7.2'
```

to my Gemfile, run `bundle install`, and extended my User model with:

```
require 'ezcrypto'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  keyholder
  ...
end
```

but that dies with `undefined local variable or method 'keyholder'`.

Ideas on how to get this working?  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

While I was digging around for an answer, I came upon [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/shuber/attr_encrypted), which

- is actively supported
- does what I need
- worked the first time

So I don't need an answer to the OP (unless you feel compelled to do so...).  Hope this helps someone else.